# Do we need the axiom of choice in here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> Axiom of choice: Given $\mathbb{F}$ is a set of non-empty sets. Then, there is a function $f$ with $\text{Dom}(f)=\mathbb{F}$ such that, for every $A \in \mathbb{F}$, $f(A) \in A$.
>
> The function $f$ is called a choice function of $\mathbb{F}$.

Every well ordered set $X$ is isomorphic to an ordinal and has a first element $\{ x_0 \}$. So, can't we just say that we have a choice function which is: $f(A)=x_0$ for every $x \in X$?

Comment: Not every set can be well-ordered though (when not accepting the axiom of choice).

Comment: This is still a bit confused, I’m afraid. How do you know that the first element of $X$ is a singleton set? Perhaps the first element of $X$ is the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers. Or did you mean that $x_0$ itself is the first element of $X$? In any case, why should this first element of $X$ be an element of any other element of $X$?

Comment: @Arthur: Shir is asking only about sets that **can** be well-ordered.

Comment: Also, "$f(A)=x_0$ for every $x\in X$" is non-sensical.

Comment: What is the relationship between $A$ and $X$?  What are you trying to prove?

Comment: @Brian: There is a difference between "can be" and "are". Especially in this context.

Comment: @Asaf: Of course, but I was addressing the specific comment; time enough to deal with the other issue if it turned out to be needed. And on my original very tentative interpretation of the question it wouldn’t have been needed: I originally thought that Shir was probably looking for a choice function on $\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I meant without ℘(X)∖{∅}. I also meant x_0 to be the element of X which is mapped to $\phi \in \alpha$ by the isomorphism, where $\alpha$ is the suitable ordinal. And now that I think of it. you are right, and also, the isomorphism $X \rightarrow \alpha$ might not be obvious as well.. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No. You still need some form of the axiom of choice. Specifically in order to **choose** the isomorphism with the ordinal.

This is apparent in the Russell socks example, where you have a countably infinite set of *pairs* without a choice function. So you a situation where the family itself can be well-ordered, and all its members can be well-ordered, but no choice function.

---

In the case where each set is also given with its well-ordering, then the answer is yes. Picking the minimal of each set is a choice function. Compare this to the following theorem:

> **Theorem.** The set $A$ can be well-ordered if and only if $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ admits a choice function.

The $(\Longrightarrow)$ direction is exactly this. Since $A$ can be well-ordered, fixing such ordering induces (uniformly) a well-ordering on every non-empty subset of $A$, and picking the minimal element is indeed a choice function.

The other direction is slightly more technical, and is similar to the general proof that the axiom of choice implies the well-ordering theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed if every $A\in\mathbb F$ is well-ordered (for example because $\bigcup\mathbb F$ is well-ordered). Then $A\mapsto\mathop{\rm min}A$ is a choice function. However, you do not say if and whence you got these well-orderings.

Comment: This is not quite correct.  If each set in $\mathbb{F}$ is well-ordered in some _uniform_ way (_e.g._, if $\bigcup \mathbb{F}$ is well-ordered, or if each set in $\mathbb{F}$ is a pair of shoes so we can declare the left shoe to always come before the right shoe), then we can get a choice function by using an appeal to this uniform way of well-ordering each of these sets.  However, as Asaf mentions in his answer, even if each set in $\mathbb{F}$ has exactly **two** elements (and so each is clearly well-orderable), some appeal to the Axiom of Choice may be necessary to get a choice function.

Comment: @ArthurFischer, I wrote “well-ordered”, not “well-orderable”. As you point out, AC may be needed to get from the latter to the former when dealing with infinitely many sets. On the other hand, to take up your example, every well-order set of cardinality $2$ has a canonical bijection to $2=\{0,1\}$ (as every well-ordered set has a canonical bijection to an ordinal).

Comment: If you meant something to the effect of "If $\{\langle X_i,<_i\rangle:i\in I\}$ is a family of well-ordered sets, then there is a choice function for $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$," then that's fine, and would fit into my "well-ordered in some _uniform_ way" property.  (Though perhaps your answer should be a bit more clear on this point.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer, I meant what I wrote. Your last comment seems somewhat off though.